# Input range incorrect display of value

Tags: html, range

I am not sure if I misunderstood this part. I have created an input range wherein its default/initial value will be **15**. 
However if I run it, the range default value is 16.

```
<input type="range" id="price" min="1" max="50" value="15" step="5"/>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nykzp2gL/

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `step` attribute plays the role. As per your input, values on the bar would be:

```
1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
```

When the value is 15, it takes the nearest one to 15 which is 16.

---

When the minimum is set to 0 and step 5, value is 15, values on the bar would be:

```
0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

Now the value would be 15 as you expect

---

The slider doesn't stop in between when you use `step` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

changing min value to 0 will get you a go

```
<input type="range" id="price" min="0" max="50" value="15" step="5"/>
```

> The default value is the minimum plus half the difference between the
>   minimum and the maximum, unless the maximum is less than the minimum,
>   in which case the default value is the minimum.